# Teamcity Project is not in alphabetical order

Tags: user-interface, project, teamcity, alphabetical

This is a really small gripe, but I was wondering if there was a way for the listed projects to be ordered in alphabetical fashion. I am currently using Teamcity version 7.1.5 and none of the documentations seem to allow this option, but I could've missed something. I am also using Internet Explorer 8. Any insight on this would be appreciated. Thanks!